# Postparameter giving error

Tags: android, mysql, android-intent, android-activity

Hi i have created an app which on the click of a button sends a string to the next activity and in the second activity i am using the value to retrieve the data from a database.

I am doing the following.

```
    Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // getting the value from the previous activity
    myIntent.getStringExtra("lbl_name");
    postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", lbl_name//passing the name to the database .getText().toString()));
```

The problem is that it is not recognising lbl_name.

I searched the internet but could not find the solution.
Please tell me whether i am doing it right.

code for passing the value.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SinglePlaceActivity.this,RecoProd.class);
                                        myIntent.putExtra("lbl_name", "lbl_name");
                                        SinglePlaceActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Code to access database.

```
public class RecoProd extends Activity {
    EditText pd;
    TextView error;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try {
            Class<?> strictModeClass = Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode", true, Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader());

            Class<?> threadPolicyClass = Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy", true, Thread
                    .currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

            Class<?> threadPolicyBuilderClass = Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder", true,
                    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

            Method setThreadPolicyMethod = strictModeClass.getMethod("setThreadPolicy", threadPolicyClass);

            Method detectAllMethod = threadPolicyBuilderClass.getMethod("detectAll");
            Method penaltyMethod = threadPolicyBuilderClass.getMethod("penaltyLog");
            Method buildMethod = threadPolicyBuilderClass.getMethod("build");

            Constructor<?> threadPolicyBuilderConstructor = threadPolicyBuilderClass.getConstructor();
            Object threadPolicyBuilderObject = threadPolicyBuilderConstructor.newInstance();

            Object obj = detectAllMethod.invoke(threadPolicyBuilderObject);

            obj = penaltyMethod.invoke(obj);
            Object threadPolicyObject = buildMethod.invoke(obj);
            setThreadPolicyMethod.invoke(strictModeClass, threadPolicyObject);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String TAG = null;
            Log.w(TAG, ex);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recomain);
        Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // getting the value from the previous activity
        String lbl_name= myIntent.getStringExtra("lbl_name");//< get lbl_name from Intent
        pd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

        error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showresult);


                postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", lbl_name
                        ));


                // String valid = "1";

                DownloadWebPageTask dw = new DownloadWebPageTask();
                dw.execute("");

    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.1.7/abc/check2.php", postParameters);  
                    String res = response.toString();
                    // res = res.trim();
                    res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    // error.setText(res);
                    try{
                        res = "";
                  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(res);
                        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.i("prod_id","id: "+json_data.getInt("prod_id")+
                                        ", prod_name: "+json_data.getString("prod_name")+
                                        ", prod_category: "+json_data.getString("prod_category")+
                                        ", prod_cost: "+json_data.getDouble("prod_cost")
                                );
                                //Get an output to the screen
                                res += "\n" + json_data.getInt("prod_id") + " -> "+ json_data.getString("prod_name");
                        }
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }

                try{
                 error.setText(res);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          
                }   
           }
                 catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
           }
            }
            return response;

               }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code of putting the value in `Intent`.

Comment: Hi anyone know the solution to the above problem even i am facing the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to extract `lbl_name` value from Intent as :

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // getting the value from the previous activity
 String lbl_name= myIntent.getStringExtra("lbl_name");//< get lbl_name from Intent
 postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product",lbl_name));
```

or if lbl_name is static in prev Activity then u can access it as:

```
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product",
                              Your_prev_Activity_Name.lbl_name));
```

Comment: @user1844638 : this code get lbl_name from prev Activity and added it to BasicNameValuePair as value of product

Comment: @user1844638 : plz share code where u are calling database in your code and explain more about issue

Comment: @user1844638 : i see it you are getting response from server ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23542/discussion-between-user1844638-and--k)

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the string value in `Intent` as below:

> ```
>      Intent myIntent = new Intent(SinglePlaceActivity.this,RecoProd.class);
>        myIntent.putExtra("lbl_name", "lbl_name");
>        SinglePlaceActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
> ```

Access the value as below using `getString();`

> ```
> Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // getting the value from the previous activity
> String lbl_name=myIntent.getString("lbl_name");
> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
> postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", lbl_name//passing the name to the database .getText().toString()));
> ```